# Trapping during the week

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The medrosh criticizes Eisov for trapping his father with questions such as "must one tithe salt," yet doesn't specify that it was shobbos, so there should be no melucha of "tzud"! Is this proof that the Avos kept shobbos all week long?

---

**This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).**

Comment: יש צד לומר כן.‏

Answer (score 11):

It can't be, because the verse ([Genesis 22:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0122.htm#3)) states:

> וישכם אברהם בבקר
>   And Avraham rose early in the morning

but we know the Rama rules ([Shulchan Aruch OC 281:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=119)) that we start davening late on Shabbat morning. Therefore, we can conclude that it was not Shabbat for Avraham on that day.

Furthermore, [Genesis 27:25](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0127.htm#25) relates about Yitzchak:

> ויגש לו ויאכל, ויבא לו יין וישת
>   And he brought him food and he ate; and he brought him wine and he drank

but we know the Shulchan Aruch rules ([OC 271:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=92)) that you can only eat *after* saying kiddush on Shabbat. Therefore, we can conclude that it was not Shabbat for Yitzchak on that day.

Furthermore, in Genesis [28:22](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0128.htm#22) Yaakov says:

> אעשר אעשרנו לך
>   I will separate a tithe to you

but we know the Shulchan Aruch rules ([OC 307:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=200)) that you can't speak on Shabbat about doing forbidden labor even after Shabbat. Therefore, we can conclude that it was not Shabbat for Yaakov on that day.

Comment: It was Tuesday, in fact! ...ביום השלישי וישא אברהם את עיניו

Comment: Although, Avraham went to do a kiddush Hashem that day.  It is common practice that when one has to go to a kiddush that he will get up early and daven hashkama even on Shabbos.

Comment: If it said he ate and he drank wine, granted.  but it saysויאכל , ויבא לו יין וישת- he brought him the wine after eating.  Mashma that Yitzchok didn't have wine beforehand and he must have made kiddush on hamotzi.

Comment: Also, there's no raya from mimtzo cheftzecha because maaser is cheftzei shamayim.  However, there is a raya from the fact that Yaakov promised to give maaser.  Since maaser is like mesaken, it would be asur to separate on shabbos.  So when would he give it if there was shabbos during the week?!

Comment: @YDK Maaser is only cheftzei shamayim according to rebbi meir. We paskin like chachamim that it is ours. See [sukkah 35a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=35&format=pdf) towards the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

The Avos did not keep shabbos all week.  The midrash was critical that Esav was tzayid b'fiv- he trapped with his mouth.  The trapping was done kilachar yad, in an unusual way.  This was a violation of שֵׁשֶׁת יָמִים תַּעֲבֹד וְעָשִׂיתָ כָּל-מְלַאכְתֶּךָ.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the *avos* kept *shabas* all week long, but the *imahos* did not. Consider:

- In *B'reshis* 14:22, *Avraham* refuses to take money, telling the king of *S'dom* to keep it for himself and give it to others. Of course, this was because *Avraham* couldn't take money on *shabas* (i.e, every day).
- In chapter 18, *Avraham* brings food to his visitors, but only *Sara* and "the young man" prepare it.
- In 27:9, *Rivka* tells *Yaakov* to bring goats, but offers to prepare them, herself, for eating.

While you can ask how *Avraham* cut animals in half (15:10), this was presumably on a direct command (not stated in the *pasuk*) from *Hashem*, which of course overrides a general *mitzva*.

And his "repaying his credit" (*Rashi* to 13:3) was done not with money but with services, which can be done on *shabas*: he was a *magid*, an itinerant preacher, who of course can work on *shabas*.

You may ask about *Yitzchak*'s digging wells in 26:18, 22. But we see in verses 19 and 21 that his servants did the digging. The two interior *p'sukim* specifying it was his servants surrounded by the two saying "*Yitzchak*" serve as a *k'lal ufrat uchlal, i ata dan ela k'en hap'rat*, so we see that all the wells were dug by people affiliated with *Yitzchak*. None, however, were actually dug by him: what do you take him for, a *m'chalal shabas, chas v'shalom*?

Comment: There's a halachah that "one may cut up a dead animal for dog food" (Orach Chaim 324:7). And since the bris bein habesarim was to inform Avraham about the Egyptian slavery and the geulah from it, at which לא יחרץ כלב לשונו, which leads to לכלב תשליכון אותו, then it follows that the animals were being cut up for a valid purpose on Shabbos - so no melachah there.

Comment: Don't forget how Leah sells the dudaim and Rachel rode on a camel, both things one wouldn't be able to do on Shabbat.